# Holo action bar not showing when I add styles to multiple android versions

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, styles, android-manifest

I have made two styles.xml:s, one in values and one in values-v11.

/res/values/styles.xml

```
    <resources>
    <style name="appTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"> </style>   
    </resources>
```

/res/values-v11/styles.xml

```
    <resources>
    <style name="appTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#3b5998</item>        
    </style>
    </resources>
```

AndroidManifesr.xml

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/pic"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/appTheme"
     >
```

When I run this program on a android 4.2 devices the action bar disappears, so my guess is that the 4.2 devices also goes to /res/values/styles.xml to get it's styles. So what am I doing wrong?

EDIT! 
I found the issue, in /res/values-v11/styles.xml the `parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"` in the "MyActionBar" style should be `parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar"` or `parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar"`

Answer (score 0):

You have set your `android:targetSdkVersion` to **16**, which is Android 4.1 Jellybean.

Android 4.2 is version **17**, so try changing your uses-sdk to this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```